# Numpy `resize` gives an unexpected array size when using -1 syntax

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand the difference between `numpy.resize` and `numpy.reshape`. I know that `resize` will return a new array and that `reshape` will maintain the same underlying data and only adjust the size (I'm assuming it does this by changing the stride). However, for both functions I would expect to be able to use the `-1` syntax to specify an axis size. However, this appears to only work for `reshape`. For example, trying to reshape/resize this 1-D array of shape `(444,)` to an array of shape `(4, 111)` gives two different results depending on whether you use `resize` or `reshape`:

```py
import numpy as np

test = np.arange(0, 444)
print(test.shape)
print(np.resize(test, (4, -1)).shape)
print(np.reshape(test, (4, -1)).shape)
```

prints

```
(444,)
(4, 110)
(4, 111)
```

I'm assuming that I'm missing something about the `resize` function, but I would expect it to either output a shape that is compatible with `(444,)` or throw an error.

Comment: The `resize` method on the array itself explicitly forbids negative dimensions, I wonder if this method should be doing the same thing.

Comment: @user3483203 Aha, you are right. Maybe this should actually be a bug in the numpy repo...

Comment: `resize` isn't used often, and is best if you want to change the total number of elements.  That is, it can clip or pad.  Beware the function and method behave quite differently.  `reshape` can't change the total number of elements, and is widely used to change the total number of dimensions - to 2d, or 1d etc.  I wouldn't treat them as alternatives.

Comment: Where in the documentation does `np.resize` explain its use of -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.resize` behavior with `-1` is not documented.  But it can be deduced from the Python code, or the following examples:

```
In [312]: np.resize(np.arange(12),(1,-1))                                       
Out[312]: array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
In [313]: np.resize(np.arange(12),(2,-1))                                       
Out[313]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
In [314]: np.resize(np.arange(12),(3,-1))                                       
Out[314]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
In [315]: np.resize(np.arange(12),(4,-1))                                       
Out[315]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
# (5,-1) error
In [317]: np.resize(np.arange(12),(6,-1))                                       
Out[317]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])
```

So in general

```
a = np.arange(n)
np.resize(a, (m,-1))
np.reshape(a[:(n-m)], (m,-1))
```

that is it clips the input by `m` elements, and attempts the `reshape`.  Not exactly useful, is it?

In your case `test[:-4].reshape(4,-1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Going through the source code of [`np.resize`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1303-L1374), you can see what is going on, and that `-1` was never intended as an input:

```
def resize(a, new_shape):
    if isinstance(new_shape, (int, nt.integer)):
        new_shape = (new_shape,)
    a = ravel(a)
    Na = len(a)   # Na = 444
    total_size = um.multiply.reduce(new_shape)   # total_size = 4 * -1 = -4 (?!?)
    if Na == 0 or total_size == 0:
        return mu.zeros(new_shape, a.dtype)

    n_copies = int(total_size / Na)    # n_copies = 0, luckily
    extra = total_size % Na            # -4 % 444 = 440 (this is where the 110 comes from)

    if extra != 0:  # True
        n_copies = n_copies + 1        # n_copies = 1 
        extra = Na - extra             # extra = 444 - 440 = 4

    a = concatenate((a,) * n_copies)   # a stays same
    if extra > 0:                      # True
        a = a[:-extra]                 # a = a[:-4]
    return reshape(a, new_shape)       # this is .reshape(4, -1) which now gives (4, 110)
```